# How to show show the address in while clicking the info window in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `Google Map API`, it is working fine, but I want to change the marker color, like suppose male means yellow marker and female means I want to show the blue color marker. 
How can do this?
If you want to know gender details, click the marker, after that pop up open from here i am displaying the gender details like he is Male or Female

```js
var res = {
                  "status": "success",
                  "count": 3,
                  "data": [{
                      "tripId": "1",
                      "pickupLatitude": "12.956413",
                      "pickupLongitude": "77.695380",
                      "empName": "Arun",
       "gender":"Male",
                      "pickupTime" : "9.30 AM"
                    },
                    {
                      "tripId": "1",
                      "pickupLatitude": "12.956107",
                      "pickupLongitude": "77.694994",
                      "empName": "Kohila",
       "gender":"Female",
                       "pickupTime" : "9.40 AM"
                    },
                    {
                      "tripId": "1",
                      "pickupLatitude": "12.955639",
                      "pickupLongitude": "77.694932",
                      "empName": "Dinesh",
       "gender":"Male",
                      "pickupTime" : "9.50 AM"
                    }
                  ],
                  "travlledLocation": [
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956664",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.696829"
                      },
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956604",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.696480"
                      },
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956523",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.696021"
                      },

                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956413",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.695380"
                      },
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956335",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.695029"
                      },
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956230",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694997"
                      },

                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956107",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694994"
                      },
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.955934",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694970"
                      },
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.955639",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694932"
                      },
                      {
                          "Travlinglatitude": "12.955380",
                          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694902"
                      }
                  ]
                };
          var geocoder;
          var map;
          var directionsDisplay;
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
          var locations = res.travlledLocation.map(function(o, i) {

            
            return [
              i == 0 ? 'Start' : i == res.travlledLocation.length - 1 ? 'Going From Here' : i,
              o.Travlinglatitude,
              o.Travlinglongitude,
              i + 1
            ]
          });

          var waypoints = res.data.map(function(o) {
            return {
              empName: o.empName,
              pickupTime: o.pickupTime,
               gender: o.gender,
              lat: o.pickupLatitude,
              lng: o.pickupLongitude
            }
          });

         initialize();
          function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
              suppressMarkers: true
            });


            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 10,
              //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25), // 
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;
            var request = {
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              if (locations[i][3] == 1 || locations[i][3] == locations.length) {

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                  map: map,
                  i: locations[i][0],
              

          icon: {
     url : locations[i][0]=='Start' ?'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-8055c322ae4049897caa15e5331940f2.png' : 'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-76f453c62108782f0cad9bfc2da1ae9d.png',
     scaledSize: locations[i][0]=='Start'? new google.maps.Size(40, 40) :new google.maps.Size(45, 45)

                  }
                });
              }

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(marker.i);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
              })(marker, infowindow));

              if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
              else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();


            }
            //push the waypoints to request.waypoints array
            waypoints.forEach(function(v, i) {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(v.lat, v.lng),
                map: map,
                icon: {
                  url: 'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-56165014858e6dbadaf3ba00d782f125.png',
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45, 45)
                },
                data: v
              });
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent('<b>Employee Name : </b>' + marker.data.empName + '<br><b>pickupTime : </b>' + marker.data.pickupTime+ '<br><b>Gender : </b>' + marker.data.gender);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
              })(marker, infowindow));
            })

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
              }
            });
          }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
 html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
  <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY">
    </script>
```

> My Updated Question

from here i click green color icon means showing Start, and click the red color icon means showing Going From Here, Instead of this I want to display the address, can you please update your answer –

Comment: When you set the icon, just like you do with start and end simply reference a different icon url

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var res = {
  "status": "success",
  "count": 3,
  "data": [{
      "tripId": "1",
      "pickupLatitude": "12.956413",
      "pickupLongitude": "77.695380",
      "empName": "Arun",
      "gender":"Male",
      "pickupTime" : "9.30 AM"
    },
    {
      "tripId": "1",
      "pickupLatitude": "12.956107",
      "pickupLongitude": "77.694994",
      "empName": "Kohila",
      "gender":"Female",
       "pickupTime" : "9.40 AM"
    },
    {
      "tripId": "1",
      "pickupLatitude": "12.955639",
      "pickupLongitude": "77.694932",
      "empName": "Dinesh",
      "gender":"Male",
      "pickupTime" : "9.50 AM"
    }
  ],
  "travlledLocation": [
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956664",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.696829"
      },
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956604",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.696480"
      },
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956523",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.696021"
      },

      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956413",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.695380"
      },
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956335",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.695029"
      },
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956230",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694997"
      },

      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.956107",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694994"
      },
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.955934",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694970"
      },
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.955639",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694932"
      },
      {
          "Travlinglatitude": "12.955380",
          "Travlinglongitude": "77.694902"
      }
  ]
};
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var map;
          var directionsDisplay;
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
          var locations = res.travlledLocation.map(function(o, i) {

            
            return [
              ((i == 0) || (i == res.travlledLocation.length - 1)) ? {lat: o.Travlinglatitude, lng: o.Travlinglongitude} : i,
              o.Travlinglatitude,
              o.Travlinglongitude,
              i + 1
            ]
          });

          var waypoints = res.data.map(function(o) {
            return {
              empName: o.empName,
              pickupTime: o.pickupTime,
              gender: o.gender,
              lat: o.pickupLatitude,
              lng: o.pickupLongitude
            }
          });

         initialize();
          function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
              suppressMarkers: true
            });


            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 10,
              //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25), // 
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;
            var request = {
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              if (locations[i][3] == 1 || locations[i][3] == locations.length) {

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                  map: map,
                  i: locations[i][0],
              

          icon: {
     url : locations[i][0]=='Start' ?'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-8055c322ae4049897caa15e5331940f2.png' : 'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-76f453c62108782f0cad9bfc2da1ae9d.png',
     scaledSize: locations[i][0]=='Start'? new google.maps.Size(40, 40) :new google.maps.Size(45, 45)

                  }
                });
              }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.i.lat, marker.i.lng)
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status ==
            google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
              infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            //alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
              })(marker, infowindow));

              if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
              else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();


            }
            //push the waypoints to request.waypoints array
            waypoints.forEach(function(v, i) {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(v.lat, v.lng),
                map: map,
                icon: {
                  url: v.gender == 'Male' ? 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/V/t/A/W/N/google-maps-gris-hi.png' : 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/Z/Y/K/e/e/yellow-google-map-pin-hi.png',
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45, 45)
                },
                data: v
              });
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent('<b>Employee Name : </b>' + marker.data.empName + '<br><b>pickupTime : </b>' + marker.data.pickupTime+ '<br><b>Gender : </b>' + marker.data.gender);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
              })(marker, infowindow));
            })

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
              }
            });
          }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

When you are setting the waypoints, check for the gender & set the icon over there.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Good answer but very ugly icons

Comment: @Deckerz Hahahha.. I know, I didn't do much research on icons...HAHHAHA.

Comment: @Shiladitya, I have one more question , from here i click green color icon means showing Start, and click the red color icon means showing  Going From Here, Instead of this I want to display the address, can you please update your answer

Comment: @KaniR I would request you to update the question first. Based on the question, will provide the answer.

Comment: @Shiladitya, can you please check i updated my question

Comment: @KaniR .. You need to make an `AJAX` call `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.956413,77.695380&sensor=true` & then get the data & display. I would request you to make an attempt, then will help you out.

Comment: I am not getting , it not possible to update your answer in fiddle?

Comment: @ Shiladitya, i tried but i am not able do this, can you please update your answer. as of now i understand i have to pass ajax call , from there i want to display one formated address can you please update

Comment: @KaniR I've updated the answer, but for some reason your click event is triggering in the beginning.

Comment: Possible means update your answer, i am waiting for your reply

Comment: @KaniR That's what I meant. You should try as well from side. You can't expect everything from this forum.

Comment: @ Shiladitya, I understand, but i am new person of developement, and this google map API, i am not able understand whare i have to do change etc, that's why

Comment: Please go through the documentation. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. It's one of the best documentation, please go through.